# Unzip in a bash script

Tags: pipe, unzip, logfile

I'm trying to write a script that save me time.
One operation is to unzip files, basic.
I don't want to get the unzip-operation on screen, I mean the verbose messages.
I know about the `-q` or even the `-qq` options.
I want the unzip to be done quietly but also to log what has been done in a log file.
I don't know what to do because I'm pretty new to bash-shell and scripting.
My Bash Shell Version : `4.3.11(1)-release`.

Is it the best way ?

```
unzip -o '*.zip' &> log.txt
```

Comment: redirect your stdout (1) and stderr (2) output to your logfile

Comment: with which command? gunzip, unzip or tar?

Comment: cannot you append ‘>> xxx.log’ followed with unzip line to redirect the output?

Comment: my command is unzip -o '*.zip" / UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Debian.

Comment: where do you want to log the output of your command?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my complete script with the tips you gave me, thank you.
it's my 1st, so it's upgradable :-)
thank you again.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
printf "Un-ZR v1.0 running w/ Bash Shell v%s\n" "${BASH_VERSION}"
printf "%s\n" "$(pwd | sed "s:$HOME:~:" | sed "s:\(.\)[^/]*/:\1/:g")" &> log.txt
tree &>> log.txt
read -rsp $'\nProcessing in (3s)...\n\n' -t 3
printf "1. UnZIP\n"
unzip -o '*.zip' &>> log.txt 
printf "2. UPPER ==> lower\n"
for i in *
do mv "$i" "$(echo "$i" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')" &>> log.txt
done
find . -type f -name "*nfo" -print &>> log.txt
find . -type f -name "*diz" -print &>> log.txt
printf "3. UnRAR\n"
/bin/unrar e -r -y "*.r*" . &>> log.txt
printf "4. Delete ZIP n RAR\n"
rm -v ./*.r* &>> log.txt
rm -v ./*.zip &>> log.txt
printf "\n Log available : %s\n" "$(find . -type f -name "log*")"
read -rsp $'\nEnd\n' -t 3
exit
```

I'm not sure for the `/bin/unrar` command because I found several `unrar` on the system... It works though.